# coc-snippets popup preview with strange content and odd formatting

Tags: plugin-coc

Cheers! I'm having an odd problem with coc + coc-snippets and javascript. The preview popup for previews is formatted in a strange way:

[image]

It shows this string "javascript.jsx" and there is no syntax highlight in the snippet. The preview of the other suggestions, however, are all nicely formatted:

[image]

Does anyone have a clue on how I can somehow control the contents of the preview popup, so I can improve its contents and format it nicely?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I wonder if the snippet is just slightly formatted wrong for the popup? In markdown, I would expect there to be no space between the triple-backtick and the language name (javascript.jsx, in this case)

Comment: Thanks! The snippet file doesn't have the string "javascript.jsx" anywhere in it, so I'm not actually sure where this is coming from... Any ideas where this might be coming from?

Comment: None, unfortunately; I dont use any of those plugins, so I took a guess. Sorry to not be of further help. You might discuss with the plugin maintainers.